# Code coverage of ASP.NET core app with test done in Pester

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, pester

I have a REST service that is being tested using Pester and our PowerShell REST client (implemented using PowerShell's `Invoke-RestMethod` and friends).

How would I generate code coverage for it ?

Test is initiated using:

1. `dotnet run` to start the service in the background
2. `invoke-pester` that runs integration test

Since we don't have by the book testing here using dot net test project, nor `dotnet test` command is used, how would I generate code coverage in such scenario ?

I tried with OpenCover and it starts up the app this way and tests run trough it, but its `results.xml` is almost empty (checked debug mode and presence of PDB files)

```
$env:ASPNETCORE_URLS = 'http://localhost:3001'
OpenCover -target:"c:\program files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" -targetargs:"run --no-build --no-restore --no-launch-profile --configuration Debug"
```

Comment: Just wondering, given that ASP.NET Core has an entire integration testing framework that is extremely easy to use and automatically generates code coverage, why are you going down this path?

Comment: Because we need to develop PowerShell REST client anyway for extensive integrations as we drive REST service via shell scripts to achieve various benefits on ANY machine we encounter. This way a) we also test the pwsh REST client b) do not require anything for testing besides out of the box PowerShell c) do not require any kind of compilation which makes it easy to fix problems in-situ. Contrary to that, anything we do in specialized test projects can not be easily reused elsewhere. This worked for us fantastic for many years on highly critical projects. The only thing missing is coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it working like a charm with dotCover CLI